# Database, merging data collected in many columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem with data presentation (report tool for Iconics Genesis 64 system).
For the report I need to allow user to choose date from, date to and multiselection of device ID`s which should be reported (these are temperature measurments etc.)

Problem is, database collector has an unusual structure, so data are stored like this:

```
ID    DATE1    SAMLPLE1    DATE2    SAMPLE2    DATE3   SAMPLE3
```

There are 36 samples, until it starts collecting data in new row and I have no power to change it.
So basically I need to somehow connect all DATE columns together and SAMPLE columns together, for further analysis.

What I need is to instead having 1 row with 36 DATE and SAMPLE columns, 36 ROWS with ID in 1st column and DATE and SAMPLE next to it.

Have not figured out how to do this (I`m not so good at database engines). Any ideas?

Comment: You can't change the schema?

Comment: No I can not, it is database for Iconics TrendWorx Logger which collects data in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways around this. First if you can't alter the database at all, you will probably have to do this in application code (PHP or whatever you're using. If you are going to need it often, I might suggest creating a view: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

In anycase, you can use this to agregate them:

```
(SELECT DATE1 as DT, SAMPLE1 as SAMPLE FROM table) UNION (SELECT DATE2 as DT, SAMPLE2 as SAMPLE from table) UNION ... UNION (SELECT DATE36 as DT, SAMPLE36 as SAMPLE)
```

Comment: It will be used like 1-3 times a week, not more often I think. So I should use that union command before I start all "WHERE" comparissions or after it?

Comment: For testing purpose I tried this one: (SELECT dbo.Eltek.Sample_Value_1 as VAL, dbo.Eltek.Sample_TDate_1 as DT FROM dbo.Eltek) UNION (SELECT dbo.Eltek.Sample_Value_2 as VAL, dbo.Eltek.Sample_TDate_2 as DT FROM dbo.Eltek) UNION (SELECT dbo.Eltek.Sample_Value_3 as VAL, dbo.Eltek.Sample_TDate_3 as DT FROM dbo.Eltek)
 WHERE DT >= #From AND DT <= #To AND dbo.Eltek.Signal_Index = #List
 ORDER BY dbo.Eltek.Signal_Index, DT And it returns Syntax Error near "WHERE". #From is parameter which I send via Web Interface

Comment: I created view in database manager like this:   `(SELECT Signal_Index as ID, Sample_TDate_1 as Date, Sample_Value_1 as Value FROM dbo.Eltek) UNION (SELECT Signal_Index as ID, Sample_TDate_2 as Date, Sample_Value_2 as Value FROM dbo.Eltek) UNION ( SELECT Signal_Index as ID,Sample_TDate_3 as Date, Sample_Value_3 as Value FROM dbo.Eltek)` But when it run this query: `SELECT ID, Date, Value FROM dbo.Report WHERE Date <= #To AND Date >= #From AND ID = #List ORDER BY ID, Date` it returns nothing

Comment: Your method is working. After creating this View it works under Web Interface. It just did not respond under "test" button built in ReportWorx. Thank You